# Expressions with "and boy was I....." Idiomatic expression?

Tags: expressions, idiomatic-language, subject-auxiliary-inversion

I'm having a hard time understanding this (idiomatic expression? maybe?) What does it mean, and why is it constructed like that? Why does the verb come first?

Why is it **Boy WAS I**.. and not **Boy I WAS**....

I'm going to provide a few sentences I found online.

Boy, **am** I glad to see you!

They eat cookies for breakfast and boy **is** it good!

I once thought all women were the same. Boy, **was** I wrong!

Comment: Alternatives to exclamatory ***Boy!*** here include ***Man!, Wow!, Gosh!, Dang! Fuck!,...***

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you form a question, you invert the subject and auxiliary verb:

> Is it a cat?

For rhetorical purposes you sometimes phrase a statement as a question. The purpose of these rhetorical questions is to engage the listener. You don't expect the listener to answer the question.

This kind of rhetorical question frequently follows a word like "Boy!" which is used as an exclamation (it doesn't mean "young male human").  But other exclamation can also trigger the rhetorical question form:

> Gosh, was he a looker!

and even sometimes with no explicit exclamation:

> Am I glad to see you!

Note that I don't mark these exclamations with a question mark.

The meaning is the same as the affirmative  "I am glad to see you" but the mood is more emphatic.

Comment: And here *boy* is an interjection expressing emphasis.

Comment: You and OP only use "to be", but this construction allows other auxiliary verbs to be inverted with the subject, too. For example: "Have I got a deal for you!" "Won't that be a funny story!" "Wow, does that stink!"