# What does the phrase 'am I glad to see you' mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

I've been watching the first episode of Family Guy, and when Peter was in court, Lois went there, and he said, "Lois, am I glad to see you".

What does "am I glad to see you" mean? Its grammar structure kind of abashes me. It's not a question, but what's that then?

Comment: It's a rhetorical question - like, for example, saying ***Aren't you the lucky one**?* when your friend tells you about some stroke of luck they've just had. Or ***Who's a good boy, then**?* asked of a dog. The speaker certainly doesn't expect his "question" to actually be answered (with a response like *"**Yes**!"* or *"**Me**!"*). Those rhetorical questions are equivalent to ***You're the lucky one / a good boy**!*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Expressions with "and boy was I....." Idiomatic expression?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/335872/expressions-with-and-boy-was-i-idiomatic-expression) That one specifically asks about ***Boy, am I glad to see you!***

Comment: @FumbleFingers it helped, thank you!